# Intellij Idea won't start (clicking the app does absolutely nothing)

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I recently installed `IntellijIdea Ultimate` and after installing the program opened automatically and it worked just fine. After closing the application and trying to open it again, nothing happens. Literally just nothing happens ( not even in task manager) 
I'm trying to open `idea64.exe` . When I try to open `idea.exe` I get the error - `Failed to load JVM DLL C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll if you already have 32-bit JDK installed, define a JAVA_HOME variable in Computer > System Properties > System Settings > Environment Variables`.
This doesn't make sense to me because my computer is `64-bit` and I have installed `64-bit jdk`.

Any help would be appreciated . Here's my system variables - 
`JAVA_HOME` ->

[image: JAVA_HOME]

`Path` :

[image: PATH]

Comment: minor text adjustments

Answer (score 0):

**FIXED** : 
After browsing the whole internet, I didn't find anything. So basically if anyone else have same issue my solution was : I had installed multiple versions on Intellij Idea, so I deleted every single one except the latest version ( Which was failing to startup) . After uninstalling other versions, this worked without any problem .